# Por que o botão com sinal de menos (remover) não funciona ao clicá-lo?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um campo de texto com um botão de adicionar ao lado. Quanto clico no botão ele adiciona outro campo de texto com um botão de remover ao lado. A idéia é que quando clico nos sucessivos botões de remover, ele remova os campos de texto; mas não importa qual clico, não funciona!

Também gostaria de saber se há um jeito de não utilizar o comando e.preventDefault().

Usando Chrome 56.0.2924.87, Bootstrap 3.2.1, Jquery 3.1.1 (JsFiddle [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/rbastida/d6qbL74r/9/))

```
<form id="certameForm" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="teste_stack_overflow_01.php">

    <div class="container">

        <!-- Dt Pub DOM -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-11 inputGroupContainer">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Dt Pub DOM</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dt_pub_dom[]" name="dt_pub_dom[]" placeholder="Data de Pub. Dom." value="" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="add" name="add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Dt Pub DOM -->

        <input type="hidden" id="id_pmc_reuniao" name="id_pmc_reuniao" value="">

    </div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var btCount = 1;

    $('#add').on("click", function(e) {

        btCount = btCount + 1;

        e.preventDefault();            
        $(this)
            .closest('div.form-group')              // find the div with class '.forg-group' 
            .clone()                                // clone it
            .insertBefore('#id_pmc_reuniao');       // and insert it before input text with id='id_pmc_reuniao'  

        $('.btn-md:last')                           // find the last button with class '.btn-md' and remove it 
            .remove();             

        $('.col-sm-2:last')                         // find the last div with class '.col-sm-2' and create another button but with the minus sign
            .html('<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-md\" id=\"n' + btCount + '\" name=\"n' + btCount + '\">\n\
                   <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus\"></span></button>'); 
    });    


    $("button[id^='n']").
            on('click', function() {
                e.preventDefault(); 
        alert('clicou');
    });


});
</script>
```

Comment: Tenta colocar esse código dentro do `onclick` do `#add`, no final dele. E remove o código que você tem no `onclick` do remover. `$('button[id^=n]').unbind("click").on("click", function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();    
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });`

Comment: Tava estudando uma forma de solucionar esse erro e de repente me deparei com sua solução. Blz!!! deu certinho!!!

Comment: Que bom @LeoCaracciolo, vou criar uma resposta então.

Comment: É isso ai, já vou dar um "essa resposta é util"

Comment: Cara, na resposta você esqueceu de fazer as modificações indicadas no comentário  Tenta colocar esse código dentro do onclick do #add, no final dele. E remove o código que você tem no onclick do remover. $('button[id^=n]').unbind("click").on("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent().parent().remove(); });

Comment: é possível não deixar aquele espaço que fica quando deletamos campos de texto e incluímos outros na sequência? Também gostaria de saber porque da utilização do unbind?

Comment: Obrigado @LeoCaracciolo, ajustei a resposta.

Comment: @RogerBastida precisava de mais um `.parent()` para remover o espaço, alterei a resposta e adicionei ele. O `unbind` remove o evento atribuido anteriormente ao elemento, eu li também que o `.off()` subistitui ele a partir do `jQuery 3.0`.

Comment: Blz @RogerBastida, retirei a minha resposta!

Answer (score 1):

Altere seu `javascript`, usando o `unbind` para remover o evento `click`, e coloque dentro da função de adicionar, para que toda vez que criar um elemento novo ele remove os eventos e cria de novo. Também adicionei 2 `parent` para remover o elemento todo, se não quiser pode tirar.

> As of jQuery 3.0, .unbind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by
>   the [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already
>   discouraged.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var btCount = 1;

    $('#add').on("click", function(e) {

        btCount = btCount + 1;

        e.preventDefault();            
        $(this)
            .closest('div.form-group')              // find the div with class '.forg-group' 
            .clone()                                // clone it
            .insertBefore('#id_pmc_reuniao');       // and insert it before input text with id='id_pmc_reuniao'  

        $('.btn-md:last')                           // find the last button with class '.btn-md' and remove it 
            .remove();             

        $('.col-sm-2:last')                         // find the last div with class '.col-sm-2' and create another button but with the minus sign
            .html('<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-md\" id=\"n' + btCount + '\" name=\"n' + btCount + '\">\n\
                   <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus\"></span></button>'); 

        $('button[id^=n]').unbind("click").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove(); 
        });
    });    

    $('button[id^=n]').unbind("click").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove(); 
    });

});
```

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo , por que é necessário repetir esta linha **$('button[id^=n]').unbind("click").on("click" ..** dentro do onclick do #add sendo que ja existe outro fora com **$('button[id^=n]') ...** ?

Comment: @RogerBastida para colocar o evento no click do novo elemento criado. O outro que fira fora seria para colocar o evento em elementos já criados, por exemplo, que vieram do `PHP`